# Not sure if my mapping worked in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, mysql, apache, laravel, elasticsearch

Im using ES with my Laravel app using this [Elasticquent](https://github.com/adamfairholm/Elasticquent) package.

My mapping looks like this before I index my DB:

```
'ad_title' => [
            'type' => 'string',
            'analyzer' => 'standard'
        ],
        'ad_type' => [
            'type' => 'integer',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
        ],
        'ad_type' => [
            'type' => 'integer',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
        ],
        'ad_state' => [
            'type' => 'integer',
            'index' => 'not_analyzed'
        ],
```

But when I do the API call _mapping?pretty afterwards

My mapping looks like this:

```
"testindex": {
        "mappings": {
            "ad_ad": {
                "properties": {
                    "ad_city": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "ad_id": {
                        "type": "long"
                    },
                    "ad_state": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
                    "ad_title": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "analyzer": "standard"
                    },
                    "ad_type": {
                        "type": "integer"
                    },
```

Shouldnt I be able to see **'index' => 'not_analyzed'** in my mapping afterwards? Or does **'index' => 'not_analyzed'** not show in the map structure afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the mapping did not get applied.  You would see the not_analyzed in the mapping API if it was applied correctly.

Make sure that you apply the mapping BEFORE you write any data.  We apply the mapping on application startup to verify the mapping is always correct and to apply any mapping updates.

Here is a sample of how to apply a mapping:

```
PUT hilden1

PUT hilden1/type1/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "regular": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "indexSpecified": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

To verify that mapping use the GET api

```
GET hilden1/type1/_mapping
```

You should see that the field "regular" only specifies it's type, where as "indexSpecified" is listed as not_analyzed.  Here is the output from my machine running ES 1.4.4

```
{
   "hilden1": {
      "mappings": {
         "type1": {
            "properties": {
               "indexSpecified": {
                  "type": "string",
                  "index": "not_analyzed"
               },
               "regular": {
                  "type": "string"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Is this written anywhere in the docs? I got told that index : not_analyzed shouldnt show up when making the ?pretty api call. And that only analyzer : x should be visible. And that one shows up in my example above - "analyzer": "standard"

Comment: The GET mapping API is going to show you the current mapping for your index or type.  The ?pretty part just formats the json, I don't believe it changes the structure of what is returned.

Comment: Okok, well I did as you told me. And I cant see anything in my logs. So not sure why 'index' => 'not_analyzed' wont show up :/

Comment: I included sample code you can use in Sense, hopefully that helps to clarify.

Comment: Thanks alot! Strange that it wont apply not_analyzed into my mapping then. I cant se error/warnings in my logs either. I will try to ask some other people (using the same package as me) if they have tried to apply not_analyzed